# If Then statement errors - User Account Types

Tags: php

I'm trying to build a basic header drop down nav for my three user account types, but they have different options depending on the account type. My code is throwing errors. Code is as follows:

```
<div class="btn-group pull-right">
              <?php if ($this->logged_in):
              $is_a = ($this->logged_in_usertype == App_Model_Users::TYPE_A);
              $is_b = ($this->logged_in_usertype == App_Model_Users::TYPE_B);
              $is_c = ($this->logged_in_usertype == App_Model_Users::TYPE_C);
              ?>
              <a class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                <i class="icon-user"></i> <?php echo $this->logged_in_nickname;?>
                <span class="caret"></span>
              </a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <?php if ($is_b):?>

                <li><a href="/profile/<?php echo $this->logged_in_slug;?>/one">Page Option One</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="/profile/<?php echo $this->logged_in_slug;?>/two">Page Option Two</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="/profile/<?php echo $this->logged_in_slug;?>/page/three">Page Option 3</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="/profile/<?php echo $this->logged_in_slug;?>/four">Page Option 4</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>

                  <?php if ($is_a):?>
                    <li><a href="/profile">Account-type 2 Profile</a></li>
                  <?php endif;?>

                <?php endif;?>
                <li><a href="/member">Account Settings</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="/logout" id="logout-link">Sign Out</a></li>
              </ul>
              <?php else:?>                
              <a class="btn" href="/login">
                <i class="icon-user"></i> Register / Login
              </a>
              <?php endif;?>
            </div>
```

I think my problem is the 2nd if statement for (if is_a)... but I'm not sure - I'm rather new to php. Could someone please help me with the correct way to construct this if statement w/ as little changes as possible to the code?

Comment: If $is_a will only run if $is_b is true. However, to fully debug, would need to see more code.

Comment: Got it - your comment above helped me realize tho.  just needed to move the ($is_a) if statement outside the ($is_b)...boneheaded rookie mistake.

Comment: What errors.........?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you post the actual error here, to inspect.

and you have a syntax error on line 32

```
<?php else:?>
```

And the second if is inside the fist if statment

Comment: yea that was it - i just needed to move the 2nd if outside the first if...I appreciate it.  I'll be sure to put the specific error messages in next time...

Comment: try use sublime text 2 with php plugin it is very light and can find silly error, everytime :)